# Sources of Philadelphia Quaker records besides Swarthmore College

Tags: united-states, pennsylvania, quakers

I have an ancestor who was born in 1811 in Philadelphia, per her death record and census records.  She was married in Ireland and the births of her children are listed in the Quaker records in the Ulster Monthly Meetings (she had joined the Lisburn meeting).  I hired the Quaker records expert at Swarthmore to look for her birth record and any other records about her family, but he couldn't find any.  Are there other repositories that have Philadelphia Quaker records?

I tried on the Irish side to get the record of her presenting her removal certificate, but they have apparently lost those records from that era.

My grandmother had said that this ancestor and her parents were devout Quakers.  She left Philadelphia for Ireland after her parents died (to live with a cousin).

Here are the particulars: Her name was Isabella Johnson Green and her parents were Richard Green and Sarah Johnson.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to Hill's online index, where you can look up the locations of where the meeting records are held.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an extensive list of Quaker resources, but here are some links to guides and repositories to help you get started.

For Philadelphia records:

- a digital copy of Jack Eckert's [Guide to the records of Philadelphia yearly meeting](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/363543?availability=Family%20History%20Library) is available to view in the Family History Library's online book collection

> Covers eastern Pennsylvania, western New Jersey, Delaware, and the
>   eastern shore of Maryland. Records, described in detail in this guide
>   are deposited jointly at Friends Historical Library of Swarthmore
>   College and the Quaker Collection of Haverford College Library.

For Pennsylvania Records:

- Also available at the FHL: a digital version of the [Inventory of church archives, Society of Friends in Pennsylvania](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/205420?availability=Family%20History%20Library) created by the WPA's Historical Records Survey
- FamilySearch Catalog Subject Search: [Quakers:Pennsylvania](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&query=%2Bsubject%3AQuakers&subjectsOpen=316550-50)

General Resources:

- NEHGS (The New England Historical and Genealogical Society) has a guide to [Quaker Genealogy](http://www.americanancestors.org/education/learning-resources/read/quaker-guide) which has an overview of their holdings, including the records themselves, finding aids, and books about how to use them, plus links to other sites.
- Mark Rabideau's site *Many Roads* has both a guide to [Quakers](http://www.many-roads.com/libraries/people-of-faith-religions/quakers/) and a collection of freely-available texts which you can access via the site.
- Cyndi's List: [Quaker](http://www.cyndislist.com/quaker/)
- FamilySearch Wiki: [U.S. Quaker Research (Society of Friends)](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/U.S._Quaker_Research_%28Society_of_Friends%29)
- FamilySearch Wiki: [Pennsylvania Church Records: Society of Friends](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Pennsylvania_Church_Records#Society_of_Friends_.28Quakers.29)
- [Research Guide to Finding Your Quaker Ancestors](http://c.mfcreative.com/mars/landing/quaker/quaker-guide.pdf) (downloadable PDF) from Ancestry.com
- [Monthly Meetings in North America: a Quaker Index](http://www.quakermeetings.com/)

---

Update: The [Quaker research guide](http://www.americanancestors.org/education/learning-resources/read/quaker-guide) at AmericanAncestors.org (NEHGS) has the link to [Monthly Meetings in North America: A Quaker Index - quakermeetings.com](http://www.quakermeetings.com/), an online version of *Monthly Meetings in North America: An Index* by Thomas C. Hill.

Searching for [Philadelphia](https://www.quakermeetings.com/Plone/search_display?MeetingName=&County=Philadelphia&StateOrProvince=&generalSearchWord=) in the county field shows several different meeting names, each of which have their own information page about the coverage of their records and where they can be found.

Looking through the pages on each meeting, you could sort out which collections are held at Haverford College and which at Swarthmore.

Comment: It looks like Swarthmore has a complete set of Philadelphia and neighboring Camden Quaker records for the time period of my interest.  I appreciate your very through and helpful answer.